# Creating an impulse indicator when using gets package for indicator saturation in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the *gets* package to run an indicator saturation for a time series analysis. I have a pretty large wild point at one time point in my series that I would like to include in the model as an outlier.

In the vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gets/vignettes/introduction.pdf), it describes how to include other covariates in the model, giving an example of a hypothesised step shift.

> Additional covariates can be included in an IS regression model by including them in the mxreg argument.  If fixed regressors entering through mxreg induce perfect collinear with break functions in IS, then indicators are removed automatically before selection. For example, consider forcing a hypothesized step-shift in 1972 to be retained while simultaneously searching for additional shifts throughout the sample:
> `R> x1972 <- zoo(sim(so2data[, "year"])[, 26], order.by = so2data[, "year"])R> isat(yso2, t.pval = 0.01, mxreg = x1972)`

This creates the dummy variable x1972 which is 1 for 1972 and all subsequent points. However, I'm interested in a hypothesised impulse rather than step shift - i.e. creating a variable which is 1 for 1972 only and 0 for all other time points. I've read the documentation for *gets* and for *zoo* but I'm none the wiser. Any advice gratefully received!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply step indicator saturation, the following will create a step saturation for the variable.
isat(yso2, ar=NULL, mxreg=NULL, iis=FALSE, sis=TRUE, tis=FALSE, t.pval = 0.01, plot=TRUE)
However, using e.g. mSIM <- sim(y, which.ones=seq(1,40,3))
##make matrix of step-indicators, but only every third or you can modify it accordingly.